# Selenium .. Extract data then store it in txt file

Tags: java, selenium

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

      driver.get("http://edition.cnn.com/");
      Thread.sleep(4000);

                driver.findElement(By.id("search-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-field")).sendKeys("Sport");
                driver.findElement(By.id("submit-button")).click();

                List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.className("cd__headline"));

                for (  int i=0 ; i<allLinks.size();i++)
                {
                   try {


                        File file = new File("file path");


                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                        bw.write(((WebElement) allLinks.get(i)).getText());
                           System.out.println(((WebElement) allLinks.get(i)).getText());
                        bw.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

                System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
            }   // driver.close();


                //driver.quit();
    }
```

Hello programmers ; 
I got a problem of making a program that extract data from web page then store it in txt file ,

The problem I only get one head line out of 10 !!

Comment: Why are you calling the File constructor and bufferedwriter details and close in each loop. Take it  outside the loop. If you are using java7 and above use try with resource so you will not have to do any closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn FileWriter to append mode by passing true as a second argument.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

OR you can move opening and closing file outside the for loop like this:

```
    public static void main(String[]args ) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://edition.cnn.com/");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-field")).sendKeys("Sport");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit-button")).click();

    List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.className("cd__headline"));

    try {
        File file = new File("file");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for (  int i=0 ; i<allLinks.size();i++)
        {
                bw.write(((WebElement) allLinks.get(i)).getText());
                System.out.println(((WebElement) allLinks.get(i)).getText());
            }
            bw.close();
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}   // driver.close();
```